# Better way to get common keys from 2 std::maps

Tags: c++, c++11

I have references to 2 maps of type `std::map<std::string, int>`. I want to create a master list containing all the keys that both maps have in common. My current solution is as follows, but I am curious if there is a more efficient way of approaching this problem?

```cpp
const std::map<std::string, int>& map1;
const std::map<std::string, int>& map2;
std::vector<std::string> shared_keys;

// only add to master list if both contain the string as a key
for (auto& entry : map1) {
    if (map2.find(entry.first) != map2.end()) {
        shared_keys.push_back(entry.first);
    }
}
```

It would be nice if I could forgo the for loop entirely / do this as a "one-liner", but not sure how to accomplish that...

Answer (score 3):

`std::map` is sorted, so you can just use [`std::set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

You'll need a custom comparator, since you're only comparing keys ... and then you need an adapter to only use the key in the output iterator ...

A one-liner is pushing it, unless you use something like the Boost.Iterator adapters. Rough sketch (untested):

```
template <typename K, typename V>
vector<K> map_key_intersection(map<K,V> const &a, map<K,V> const &b)
{
    vector<K> result;
    using Elem = typename map<K,V>::value_type;
    set_intersection(a.begin(), a.end(),
                     b.begin(), b.end(),
                     boost::make_function_ouput_iterator(
                       [&result](Elem const &e) { result.push_back(e.first); }),
                     [](Elem const& a, Elem const& b) { return a.first < b.first; });
    return result;
}
```

NB, there are several things wrong with this in practice, even apart from the fact that ranges are a better approach if you have access:

1. The [`std::map`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html) has more than two template parameters. So, add the Compare and Allocator params to your list.
2. What if they had different Compare types? Now we might not meet the requirements of `set_intersection`.
3. What if they have the *same* Compare type, but were constructed with a **stateful** comparator that does a different thing for each instance? Weird, but possible ... and we still don't meet the ordering constraint, but it's more expensive to check.

So, to be exactly correct, you should use eg. `a.value_comp()` instead of the bare `operator<`, but you also need to be reasonably sure that both maps use the same ordering. At least, you should add a comment to the effect that it's your client's problem if they don't.

Comment: `std::map<K, V>::value_comp()` is a compare for the first of a `std::pair<const K, V>`

Comment: Good point! I was trying to avoid getting too bogged down in fiddly details ...

Comment: "*`std::map` has more than two template parameters. So, add the Compare and Allocator params to your list*" - or use a variadic template.

Comment: Might just as well take a single type param `SortedContainer`, really

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection), although as a one liner you will also get values from the one of the maps.

```
std::vector<std::pair<const std::string, int>> shared;

std::set_intersection(map1.begin(), map1.end(), map2.begin(), map2.end(), std::back_inserter(shared), map1.value_comp());
```

With C++20's ranges library (or a similar C++11 library), you can grab the keys for the intersection.

```
std::ranges::set_intersection(std::ranges::keys_view(map1), std::ranges::keys_view(map2), std::back_inserter(shared_keys));
```